# Visual Studio 2012 becomes not reponding when include RPT file in project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Excuse me, why my visual studio 2012 becomes not responding when include (include in project or copy paste the file) RPT file in project ?

Yesterday was still alright. I've tried reinstall the visual studio, include it in other projects and reset all settings via tools-> import and export settings... but the problem is still exist.

Comment: Has you tried uninstalling/reinstalling Crystal Reports?

Comment: Did you install the Crystal Report Runtime? If yes then check the installed version is 32/64. I have also this problem occasionally, I installed the latest version and  now no problem.

Comment: I've tried uninstall SAP Crystal Report and it becomes normal again. But when after i install the SAP Crystal Report again, it becomes error again. Any suggestions?